# date_default_timezone_get() symfony command line

Tags: symfony

How to fix this probleme when i use symfony command line

> Warning: date_default_timezone_get()

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set it in your `php.ini`: `date.timezone = "UTC"` for example.

Comment: Construct function with the follwing code fix my issue in appkernel.php 


public function __construct($environment, $debug)
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
        parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
    }